# Why do I see spaces between polygons in OpenGL, only on an Nvidia 720M?

Tags: opengl, rendering, nvidia

I'm developing an OpenGL application that renders `.obj` 3D models.  I use VBOs to render the polygons.  Using the same code, the loaded models appear fine on all PCs, *except* on my Nvidia 720M.

My laptop sports an Intel HD 4000 embedded graphics GPU, and an Nvidia 720M. When I use the Intel GPU, it looks fine, but when I load it on the Nvidia 720M, spaces appear around polygons like so:

On Nvidia 720M GPU:

[image: 3D-rendered car, with gaps around polygons]

On everything else:

[image: 3D-rendered car, with gaps around polygons]

No other 3D application that runs on the Nvidia 720M GPU has the same issue.  I am using the latest drivers.

Is this a problem with my application?  How can I fix it?

Comment: 1. Probably; 2. Probably. Can't say much more without the application source.

Comment: You don't mention OpenGL version (modern or fixed-function), and if modern then whether or not you are using compatibility or core profile: these facts have bearing on the problem since it may well be a case of blend mode and/or how you've written your fragment shader source. Suggest you update your question & retag accordingly. And yes, it is likely your source that is the issue, even if the NVidia card is the only one acting up: you've probably written something in a way that is not conducive to uniform behaviour across different GPUs.

Comment: I am using VBOs to render the triangles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a hunch... is your GPU somehow doing polygon antialiasing? That would cause such artifacts. For example, if two neighbouring polygons each cover a particular pixel for 50%, the total coverage (alpha) for that pixel would be 75%, not 100%.

Try forcing the option off:

```
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
```

Or even:

```
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
```

Comment: Wow, disabling polygon smoothing worked! Thanks a lot! :D